# Naked domain URL not resolving at home page

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, ssl, amazon-route53

I have an E-commerce platform with about 30 stores live, all made up with NodeJS (express) and Angular and is hosted on Azure.

We have SSL also enabled. When I try to open without SSL for example `http://eminencepk.com` it stays at connecting in chrome. If I add `http://eminencepk.com/?en` or anything after `/` it works perfectly. Working with https as well.

this domain is managed on Amazon Route 53. Similar thing Happening to 3 more stores. It's not even reaching our server.

PS: **I am just looking for possible problems because its also working fine on VPN.**

[image]

Comment: This seems to be working for me.

Comment: Forgot to mention, also works on VPN

Comment: See new edits. I am just looking for any possible reason.

Comment: I just navigated to `http://nishatlinen.com` and it resolved and eventually redirected to `https://usa.nishatlinen.com/` successfully for me. I did this in Chrome with no extensions. Is it possible that you have an extension interfering? I'd also look to see if it is possible that the `usa.` redirect is successful but perhaps other subdomain redirects have an error in them?

Comment: Tried on multiple machines. didn't work.
I am expecting it some issue at ISP side, but I need to have a good logical reason to tell the client.

Answer (score 0):

For me it seems to work fine but I see one issue that might have happened.

Maybe the website used to redirect to HTTPS using 301 Moved Permanently. Your browser or proxy has cached the new location (as it should) and tries to access the HTTPS version (which currently doesn't work because of a bad certificate) without checking the HTTP version any more and it cannot proceed. Other URLs with some query parameters have not been cached and result in a fresh request to the HTTP server that currently doesn't redirect to HTTPS.

This is the only logical explanation that I see to the symptoms that you described.

See this answer for some info on the types of redirects and the consequences of their usage:

- [Redirect POST to POST using Express JS routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40514912/redirect-post-to-post-using-express-js-routes/40515723#40515723)

Comment: Yes, We recently moved to HTTPS and its working fine on HTTPS, issue is with HTTP, and Its working fine on VPN that means the issue is something at locally. But on the other side, as in the screenshot, I am trying out in Incognito, that means no CACHE.

Comment: RSP makes a good point - could be a network appliance doing some caching that isn't in/on your machine. That could also explain why VPN gets you around it.